# Post query object name is not included?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf

I am making a post call to a service like this,

```
var ms = [], url = myServer + "/government.svc/Users/Add";
ms.push({
    ID: 210,
    UserID: "S-1-691534-18",
    Role: "1",
    StartDate: myUser.startDate,
    UpdateM: true
});

var user = {
    Email: myUser.desc,
    FirstName: myUser.FN,
    LastName: myUser.LN,
    Memberships: ms,
    .. added all other properties like this  "PropertyName" : ""
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(user));

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ pUser: user }) + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
```

After stringify, I am getting this in console

```
"{"pUser":
{
"ID":"S-1-691534-18",
"Email":""user.one@google.com",
"FirstName":"User",
"LastName":"One",
"Memberships":[{"ID":"210","UserID":"S-1-691534-18","Role":"1","StartDate":"04/09/2015","UpdateM":true}],
"Username":"",
"Phone":"",
"Mobile":"",
"AddressID":"",
"Address":"",
"Photo":"",
"Bio":"",
"Notes":"",
"EmailNotes":"",
"IsNaugthy":"",
"CurrentMembershipID":"",
"MembershipStatus":"",
"OtherDate":"",
"MemAckwww":"",
"EatHabbits":""
}
}"
```

My Server side method,

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Users/Add")]
    UserDetails AddUser(User pUsers);
```

**Error**

400 - bad request.

I am getting null for pUser when debug server side in WCF, so I think I need to send above var user object as user object not a long string ??

**My WCF Data Contract**

My server side has a lot more DataMembers then what I am sending, I don't see how that is creating a issue ?

Do I must need to match all members in my client side code to make it work ?

**Edit**

My server side class,

```
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID;
    [DataMember]
    public string Username;
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName;
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName;
    [DataMember]
    public string Phone;
    [DataMember]
    public string Mobile;
    [DataMember]
    public string Email;
    [DataMember]
    public int? AddressID;
    [DataMember]
    public string Address;
    [DataMember]
    public string Photo;
    [DataMember]
    public string Bio;
    [DataMember]
    public string Notes;
    [DataMember]
    public string EmailNotes;
    [DataMember]
    public int IsNaugthy;
    [DataMember]
    public int CurrentMembershipID;
    [DataMember]
    public string MembershipStatus;
    [DataMember]
    public string OtherDate;
    [DataMember]
    public int? MemAckwww;
    [DataMember]
    public Membership[] Memberships;
    [DataMember]
    public Eat[] EatHabbits;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried sending data to server like `JSON.stringify({pUser: user})` once?

Comment: @palaѕн just did and still get null for pUser in my WCF server side

Comment: Can you hit you action? For instance, if you have a simple method like this String Test(int id) can you hit? Does your User class match the json object you're trying to post (properties names and types)?

Comment: @RicardoPontual updated question with my class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action is expecting parameter `pUsers`. You are sending an object with the parameter name `pUser`.

Change your serverside method from

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Users/Add")]
UserDetails AddUser(User pUsers);
```

to

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Users/Add")]
UserDetails AddUser(User pUser); //changed parameter name
```

Also, ensure when sending the data that any attributes of the model which are not nullable types have a corresponding value, else the model binder will get upset.